# I am facing this problem in pyppeteer in simply login to page and logout by clicking on div anchor tag

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, puppeteer, chromium, pyppeteer

Where i am going wrong?
I just want to go on some URL fill login file fields and click on submit button and select logout div click on it and exit..

```
pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.
```

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
import time
async def main(user , password):
    browser = await launch(headless=False)
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setViewport({ 'width': 1280, 'height': 800 })
    await page.goto('someurl')
    await page.type('[ id = userName ]', user)
    await page.type('[ id = password ]', password)
    await page.click('[type = submit]')
    time.sleep(5)
    await page.screenshot({
        'path' : 'next2.png'
    })
    element = await page.querySelectorAll('div[class = pull-right]')
    await page.evaluate('(element) => element.click', element)

    await browser.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main('username , 'password@123'))
```

Comment: `(element) => element.click` looks wrong -- you probably want to call the function, `(element) => element.click()`. Also, you're missing a closing quote after `username, `.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually comes when the page is in a navigation state.
You just need to use `page.waitForNavigation`:

```
await page.waitForNavigation()
```

See [docs](https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/index#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) for more information about it. Make sure the official docs are for Node.js so you need to use a **dictionary** instead of **object**.